Can I redeem myself with a better research paper if my thesis sucks?
When I was doing my undergraduate thesis, I tried my best to create a good and at least a decent thesis. In the end, I got a B out of pity. I didn't feel like I deserve a score like that, especially when I barely could defend my project to the moderator.
Nowadays, I have a new idea for a research paper that I think could be better than before. Can I use that to redeem myself and "replace" my thesis? I really don't want my thesis to be a scar and left like that. How much will it impact my future, especially for applying a Master's Degree?

Most undergraduate theses "suck" - it is an early step in a long complicated process of becoming a researcher, a process that many (most) people writing an undergraduate theses never even start on. Learn from it and move on.

It's all part of the experience, the maturation process. Best advice I could give you is just keep truckin' on!

@JonCuster And working on projects where it's even possible to suck is an important step in that process. If you always succeed, it means you're working on trivial problems.

I didn't think anyone ever read my bachelor thesis.

@The_Gamer To expand on what Jon Custer said - many bachelor's theses aren't even publicly accessible, let alone something admissions committees are reading (also, admissions committees do not have time to read bachelors' theses). To be blunt, nobody but you will ever care about your bachelor's thesis after it is graded.

@The_Gamer Moreover, you don't need "redemption" for writing/presenting a thesis "badly". Failure/less-desireable outcomes are opportunities to learn from your mistakes and grow, not something to torture yourself over weeks after the fact. Learn from your mistakes in this thesis and apply those lessons to the next thing you write.

@Andrew - My university library records how many times my thesis has been checked out. The answer is once by me, once by my tutor on the day he marked it, and once by a student who checked it back in five minutes later. I like to think I made a difference to his life...

A thesis is a work of yours to get the title. In most cases you are supposed to be The Only Author. Anyone else's contribution to it should be in the form of advise and discussions.
You passed. You got the title. Game over.
Research papers do not need to be from just one author; most of them are based on the cooperation of multiple authors with different extents of contribution.
When you were writing your thesis as an undergrad, you were a newbie to the field and had limited time for to do the work and write about it.
Now you are a more experienced scientist and therefore your articles are of better quality. You also have more time to perform the analyses and more time to fine-tune the manuscript.
If I am to evaluate my theses, "pity" would be very generous assessment.
Think of the thesis/theses as a ground mark to compare your growth to. No-one is expecting your thesis to be brilliant. Unless you claim it was brilliant in the first place. Then they will, most of time, prove you wrong.

Undergraduate (which is more or less the first degree in a university in Europe (after 3 years)) or Master theses are there just because this is traditionally the nice thing to do. Nobody cares about them. Nobody (except your supervisor and some higher degree student punished to read it) will ever read them. They have zero value and have zero interest for anyone.
Your thesis is useless.
Now that this is clear - stop worrying about it, forget about it, and move forward. Whether you go for Academia where your PhD thesis may by miracle have any impact, or for Industry (where nobody cares), anything before has absolutely zero impact on whatever

Of course, you may be in the special case where a MSc or PhD thesis makes a difference - congratulations then. But I put that note under a line (and should probably make it very small) because this will not happen.

@Anyon Ah, I thought Sweden followed the Bologna Process? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_Process)

@Anyon: I just checked https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolognaprocessen and wat I meant is the Kandidatexamen  in Sweden -- I will update my answer to make that clear

OK, that makes sense. Many countries did indeed get rid of their Licentiate degrees as part of the Bologna process, but I guess Sweden and Finland didn't because theirs doesn't really map onto any of the standardized degrees.

To be honest, the same is practically true of most PhD theses. For most academics it's TL;DR for your work, your publications will be what they will read.

@Crazymoomin yes, agreed. This is why I made mine 42 pages long, with a one page for the introduction (that just gave two pointers to basic literature), my papers, a summary, the thank yous and an extra section where I disagree with myself. I got from the jury 4 "thanks god for the length" and 1 " you do not understand the essence of centuries of traditions when writing tomes of knowlegde"

Whether you can replace the thesis with the results of another project is a local question, but I doubt that it would be allowed. Only they can say, however.
I suggest you let it go and if the other project is something you'd want to follow up on anyway, then do so, provided you can do so without neglecting other studies.
You aren't expected to be an expert at your stage of education. Any research experience as an undergraduate is a plus for graduate admissions. And the B is an acceptable grade. Your characterization of it as a "pity" grade is invisible to others and possibly incorrect.
Take this as a learning experience and note that the limited time available for undergrad research already implies limited results. Exploring the unknown can't be done with a timetable. Experience counts. Move on. Good luck.
